# Open in Editor in Sublime Merge

Tags: sublimetext3

https://www.sublimemerge.com

I see there is an option on Sublime Merge, right-click file and `Open in Editor...`, that will open the file in the default editor (sublime text here).

However sometimes I prefer to open files on QtCreator.

How can I have multiple editors on Sublime Merge? And then choose which one to use while opening a file.